# Sorting on a numerical value using csvfix for linux - turns numbers to strings

Tags: linux, unix, csv

I'm using [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/) to sort a CSV file based on an integer (counter) value in the second column. However it seems that csvfix puts double quotes around all fields in the file, turning them to strings, before it performs the sort. The result is that the rows are sorted by the string value, such that "1000" comes before "2".

There is a command-line option `-smq` that is supposed to apply "smart quoting" but that's not helping me. If I use the command `csvfix echo -smq file.csv`, the output has no quotes around numerical fields, but when I pipe that into `csvfix sort -f 2 file.csv`, the file is written without quotes but still sorted in "string order". It makes no difference whether I include the -smq flag in the sort command or not.

Additionally I would like csvfix to ignore the first row of string headers. Csvfix issue tracking [claims this is already implemented](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/issues/detail?id=24&can=1&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary) but I can only find the `-ifn` flag that seems to cut the header row out entirely.

These seem pretty basic pieces of functionality for this tool, so I'm probably missing something very simple. Hoping someone on here has used csvfix and figured out.

Comment: Answered per Barton's response below. Thanks! Also regarding ignoring the header line, I'm handling this using the `head` command to store the first line of the file, csvfix's `-ifn` flag to ignore the header row, and then `sed "1 i $headers" file.csv` to add the header line back in after the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [on line documentation for csvfix](http://csvfix.byethost5.com/csvfix13/csvfix.html), sort has a `N` option for numeric sorts:

```
csvfix sort -f 2:N file.csv
```

Having said this, CSV [isn't a particularly good format for text manipulation](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s02.html#id2901882). If possible, you're much better off choosing DSV (delimiter separated values) such as Tab or Pipe separated, so that you can simply pipe the output to `sort`, which has ample capability to sort by field, using whatever collation method you need.

Comment: Indeed I just figured that out literally 2 minutes ago and was just composing my own answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually using csvfix to sort the output of an MS Jet database export using mdbtools' `mdb-export`, which seems to return records out of order for tables with more than 1000 records. And `mdb-export` outputs a csv. At this point I'm just happy to have gotten it all working, but I appreciate the feedback and will keep DSV in mind in the future.